# determine mac address of switch port you are connected to

Tags: c, tcp

Is it possible to figure out what is the mac address of the **switch port** you are connected to?

I was looking in tcpdump, but it seems that in each ethernet packet the MAC of the sender and destination, but not of those MAC's it passing. But i'm looking for way to find out the **MAC** of the switch you are **directly** connected to.

I should be a generic solution. For example a managed *CISCO* switch, is not a solution (yet).

I have C/C++ at my disposal or any other language.

Comment: It is unlikely the switch MAC addresses mess up with the data it transfers. You have to connect to the switch to read its internal data. Modern switches have a special RJ45 (or serial cable), or answer a specific protocol (IP level) through the regular switch ports. Need to know the device (switch) brand and name to address that particular feature. [HP](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/products/network-management/index.aspx) does it, so there is a way...

Comment: that makes sense. however i thought maybe i doing something with ARP? For my understanding, the switch needs to send the answers back to the port it came from, therefor keep track of something that tells the ports apart.

Answer (score 3):

Read this: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch#Layer_1_.28Hubs_versus_higher-layer_switches.29

In a normal switch they don't have a MAC address. Unless what you are using is a bridge.

Comment: thank you. i think i get it. however, where would for example a 3com **office connect switch** drop in?

Comment: http://www.zdtronic.com/NETWORKING/3COM-NETWORKING/3COM-3C1671600-OFFICECONNECT-GIGABIT-SWITCH-16.html

Comment: I'd say it has no MAC addresses

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP are above the switch in [network layer abstractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite). Specifically, they're at the Transport and Internet layers, respectively (Transport is above Internet).  You need to inspect the raw Ethernet packet, for Link layer data.

Comment: And he won't find what he is looking for, just the source and destination addresses.